# Invoking Beyond Compare via Git Bash with diff file as output

Tags: bash, git, beyondcompare, git-gui, gitk

I need some help adding arguments to the Git difftool.

I have Beyond Compare (BC) configured as a diff tool for Git.  If I invoke the following line, Beyond Compare will successfully open with a diffed file:
git difftool

What I would like to do is invoke a Beyond Compare diff from Git Bash but using the command-line arguments Beyond Compare allows.  For example, I'd like to set the report file BC uses to dictate the output format.  I'd also like to dictate the output file, while hopefully dictating that the output file contains a filename similar to the file being compared, such as .html.

BC's command line form is: BC     /silent

Any suggestions on how I can get the diff tool to do something like:
git difftool

Thanks!!